# avoid lint when gradle execute check

Tags: android, gradle, lint

could someone tell me a way to avoid executing "lint" each time I run in gradle check?

I've defined in build.gradle

```
lintOptions { 

    quiet true 

}
```

However, it keeps doing this task. The problem is that it takes ages each time I have to do a check.

Comment: from command line ./gradlew clean build -x  lint

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
gradle build -x lint
```

Source: [Gradle User Guide : Excluding Tasks](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:excluding_tasks_from_the_command_line)

Answer (score 45):

You can skip it using adding `-x lint` when you run the `check` task:

```
./gradlew check -x lint
```

If you want to skip it permanently you can add this to your `build.gradle` before `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.equals("lint")) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, finally I've started using this commands `./gradlew check -x lint`

Comment: For any future visitors, you may need to change "lint" to "lintVitalRelease" because #thegoogle renamed it.

Comment: @xbakesx I just disable all task with name starting with "lint", seem to work well enough

Comment: to _which_ build.gradle? and _where_? the answer is not clear

Comment: @SargeBorsch if you want to add the task.whenTaskAdded closure, you add it to your application module's build.gradle, and you can safely add that to the bottom of the file.

Comment: Please note that the whenTaskAdded closure solution is used, it will still invoke task dependencies, e.g. compiling all sources.

Comment: And for 2024 visitors, I've needed to extend that to `gradlew build -x lintVitalRelease -x lintAnalyzeDebug` to get it to finish

Answer (score 23):

I just disabled the task during project setup:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        tasks.lint.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Note: it's not necessary to put the statement inside `android.lintOptions`, but since it's configuring lint, it's nice to have them together.

Comment: perfect! worked for me. Had all other options but non worked except this

Answer (score 7):

Set `checkReleaseBuilds` to `false` will disable lint check on release build. Add following scripts to your build.gradle file:

```
lintOptions {
     /**
     * Set whether lint should check for fatal errors during release builds. Default is true.
     * If issues with severity "fatal" are found, the release build is aborted.
     */
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

(Gradle 1.1.0, as packaged with Android Studio 1.1.0)

For anyone wondering how to do this with multiple subprojects, I ended up having to disable them using the root project build.gradle file like so:

```
task lintCheck() {
    getAllTasks(true).each {
        def lintTasks = it.value.findAll { it.name.contains("lint") }
        lintTasks.each {
            it.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How / where do you call lintCheck() after it?

Comment: In my case I was able to add it as a dependency on build.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have different build variants, perhaps a more robust script solution would be

```
afterEvaluate {
  Set<Task> result = tasks.findAll { task -> task.name.startsWith('lintVital') }
  result.each { Task task ->
    task.enabled = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code to disable all lint tasks using Gradle's new configuration avoidance API:

```
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintBaseTask).configureEach {
    enabled = false
}
```

(tested on Android Gradle plugin 3.3.2.)

Comment: where you put it ?

Answer (score 1):

`-x lint` **not worked** for `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4`

you should use `-x lintVitalRelease -x lint -x lintVitalSourceSets` instead.

For example:

```bash
gradlew --stacktrace build -x lintVitalRelease -x lint -x lintVitalSourceSets
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want the lint task to work you can also:

```
project.tasks.check.dependsOn.remove("lint")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case somehow nice solutions was not working so I looked in the error file `lint-results-debug.txt` and just disable errors that was actually not real issues in my code but more bugs of limited lint. Like this one:

```
.../Users/renetik/Development/renetik-instruments-android/project/renetik-instruments-library/src/main/res/layout/controller_chord.xml:9: Error: No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal. This is a common source of bugs when children are added dynamically. [Orientation]...
```

So I added to module build gradle of renetik-instruments-library

```
android {
    ...
    lintOptions {
        disable 'IncludeLayoutParam', 'Orientation', 'UseAppTint'
    }
}
```

Now build works... and useful lint checks still there.

But also for build performance improvement of complex project this can be miracle:

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.findAll { it.name.startsWith('lint') }.each { it.enabled = false }
}
```

But you have to place or included in each module build.gradle it doesn't work in project build.gradle
If its correctly aplied you can see

> Task :renetik-instruments-app:lintVitalAnalyzeDebug SKIPPED

in Build Output console.