# Migration to Gradle plugin v.1.1.2 caused failing lint checks

Tags: android, gradle, lint

My team recently decided to use newly announced unit-testing integration in Android studio, which requires upgrading Gradle plugin version to 1.1.0 or higher. But this update caused failing of Lint task for one of our modules, with very weird error. Can anyone give an idea what might be a problem here? 
`Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2459
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:172)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:946)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope$Substitutor.substitute(Scope.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.substitute(Scope.java:435)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.superclass(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:1212)
        at com.android.tools.lint.EcjParser$EcjResolvedClass.isSubclassOf(EcjParser.java:1025)
        at com.android.tools.lint.checks.CleanupDetector.checkResourceRecycled(CleanupDetector.java:219)
        at com.android.tools.lint.checks.CleanupDetector.visitMethod(CleanupDetector.java:180)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JavaVisitor$DelegatingJavaVisitor.visitMethodInvocation(JavaVisitor.java:1314)
        at lombok.ast.MethodInvocation.accept(MethodInvocation.java:114)
        at lombok.ast.BinaryExpression.accept(BinaryExpression.java:131)
        at lombok.ast.ExpressionStatement.accept(ExpressionStatement.java:63)
        at lombok.ast.Block.accept(Block.java:106)
        at lombok.ast.Try.accept(Try.java:107)
        at lombok.ast.Block.accept(Block.java:106)
        at lombok.ast.MethodDeclaration.accept(MethodDeclaration.java:240)
        at lombok.ast.NormalTypeBody.accept(NormalTypeBody.java:57)
        at lombok.ast.ClassDeclaration.accept(ClassDeclaration.java:239)
        at lombok.ast.NormalTypeBody.accept(NormalTypeBody.java:57)
        at lombok.ast.ClassDeclaration.accept(ClassDeclaration.java:239)
        at lombok.ast.CompilationUnit.accept(CompilationUnit.java:83)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JavaVisitor.visitFile(JavaVisitor.java:263)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkJava(LintDriver.java:1491)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.runFileDetectors(LintDriver.java:1026)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkProject(LintDriver.java:882)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:433)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:374)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.run(LintCliClient.java:130)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleClient.run(LintGradleClient.java:112)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleClient$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.runLint(Lint.groovy:198)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.this$4$runLint(Lint.groovy)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint$this$4$runLint$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lintSingleVariant(Lint.groovy:173)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint$lintSingleVariant$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lint(Lint.groovy:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 47 more`

Comment: Same issue here using gradle 2.3, and the beta 1.2 plugin.  In my case, the lint error seems to come and go based on the state of other projects.   I can't figure it out, but it was working, then it was not, then it was, now it's not.

Comment: Same issue with 2.4 and 1.2.3 plugin. 

Reported to google and fixed merged in android studio 1.3
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172268 

The issue goes away using android gradle plugin 1.0.1 and gradle 2.2.1 or gradle 2.3.

Comment: before Android Gradle will get fix try to turn off checking lint http://stackoverflow.com/a/21150358

Comment: Confirmed that updating to Android Gradle plugin 1.3.0 fixes the issue. Those errors still occur, but lint now just logs them and continues rather than failing.