# Disable `lint` in Android gradle

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-lint

From the [Android Tools Project Site's Android Gradle Plugin User Guide](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Lint-support) I'm aware that it's possible to prevent Android's lint from aborting a build using:

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

I'm also aware that lint can be disabled for release builds:

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

However, is it possible to completely disable lint when running e.g. `gradle assembleDebug`?

I'm aware of the risks and for this particular project it is wasting a fair amount of time given all the build flavors we have.

Comment: Love to be able to completely turn this off. Causing me huge problems in Gradle.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143556/avoid-lint-when-gradle-execute-check/21148409#21148409 for a solution.

Comment: Lint is slow, uses lots of CPU and promotes Android style of programming which contradicts sane way of programming. There's no point in keeping lint.

Comment: @MartinVysny I'm printing your words to hang them in the office's wall... god bless u.

Answer (score 25):

Surely you can do this by adding this line in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
gradle=build -x lint -x lintVitalRelease
```

**Warning**: The above line will prevent running lint for **both debug and release builds!**

If you want  to find out more gradle hacks, speedy builds, performance improvements, this will be the best slides you'll be looking at: [Mastering Gradle 3.0](https://speakerdeck.com/snehpandya18/mastering-gradle-3)

I prepared this from a lot of different resources including Android Developer & Gradle documentation, Android Developer videos, etc - hope it helps! It really makes a huge difference in build times (incremental as well as project load time)

Comment: Still get `Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.4.0.` errors in the lint task.

Comment: I have no "gradle.properties" file. I can create one, but where should I put it, please?

Answer (score 22):

Add following lines of code inside build.gradle(app).

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        //If you want to continue even if errors found use following line
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for flavor specific lint disable. Thanks for pointers.

Comment: I want it off entirely as lint produces `The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.4.0.` errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and used all below options

- quiet true
- abortOnError false
- checkReleaseBuilds false

but at the end I found that clearing and invalidating cache would be a good option to settle the matter.